# EF 3.x: Change Primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, savechanges

I have the following model:

```
public partial class Device 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceVerizon VerizonData { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceVerizon
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public string ServicePlan { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceVerizonMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DeviceVerizon>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DeviceVerizon> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(DeviceVerizon));
        builder.HasKey(d => d.DeviceId);

        builder.HasOne(o => o.Device)
            .WithOne(o => o.VerizonData)
            .HasForeignKey<DeviceVerizon>(a => a.DeviceId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired()
            ;
    }
}

public partial class DeviceMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Device> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Device));
        builder.HasKey(d => d.Id);
        builder.HasIndex(d => d.IMEI).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

then I want to "reassign" `DeviceVerizon` from one `Device` to another:

```
        var sourceDevice = _context.Devices.Where(a => a.Id == sourceDeviceId).FirstOrDefault();
        var verizonData = _context.DeviceVerizons.Where(a => a.DeviceId == sourceDeviceId).FirstOrDefault();
            sourceDevice.VerizonData = null;
            verizonData.DeviceId = targetDeviceId;
```

and I receive

> The property 'DeviceId' on entity type 'VerizonData' is part of a key
> and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the
> principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first
> delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then...

so, when I call `sourceDevice.VerizonData = null` I try to remove this dependent, but I can't call save changes in this moment, because I have many other changes and all of them should be called in one transaction. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just reassign `verizonData.DeviceId`? Setting `sourceDevice.VerizonData = null` shouldn't be necessary. Do you get the same error if you do this instead?

Comment: @MattU the same error, if I just try to reassign: `verizonData.DeviceId = targetDeviceId;` (without `sourceDevice.VerizonData = null`)

Comment: Is 'verizonData.DeviceId` part of a primary key?

Comment: @MattU it's a primary key for DeviceVerizon at all

Comment: If `DeviceId` is a primary key on `DeviceVerizon` then it makes sense, you shouldn't be changing a primary key. I would expect it to be a foreign key that points back to `Device`.

Comment: @MattU it's primary and foreign key

Comment: Is it the primary key on `DeviceVerizon`, or is it only the primary key on `Device` while being a foreign key on `DeviceVerizon`?

Comment: @MattU `DeviceId` of `DeviceVerizon` entity is foreign key to `Id` of `Device` entity and also is primary key for `DeviceVerizon` entity

Comment: @MattU, so, only `DeviceId` is mandatory and unique for `DeviceVerizon` and can be PK.

Comment: EF (6 and Core) does not allow mutating the PK. Period. Whether it is also FK or not is irrelevant. The important is that it is PK. Same for alternate keys in EF Core.