# EF Core 3.x: copying record does not work as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, savechanges

I have the following model:

```
public partial class Device 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceVerizon VerizonData { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceVerizon
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public string ServicePlan { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceVerizonMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DeviceVerizon>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DeviceVerizon> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(DeviceVerizon));
        builder.HasKey(d => d.DeviceId);

        builder.HasOne(o => o.Device)
            .WithOne(o => o.VerizonData)
            .HasForeignKey<DeviceVerizon>(a => a.DeviceId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired()
            ;
    }
}

public partial class DeviceMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Device> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Device));
        builder.HasKey(d => d.Id);
        builder.HasIndex(d => d.IMEI).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

so, `DeviceId` is PR and FK for `DeviceVerizon`.

I want to reassign `DeviceVerizon` from one to another record of `Device`.

I tried to it just change DeviceId from source Device to target device and no success: [EF 3.x: Change Primary key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67714214/ef-3-x-change-primary-key-value)

Ok, I try to create copy of DeviceVerizon data by the following way:

```
        CreateMap<DeviceVerizon, DeviceVerizon>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DeviceId, o => o.Ignore())
            ;
```

and then:

```
            var newVerizonData = _mapper.Map<DeviceVerizon, DeviceVerizon>(verizonData);
            newVerizonData.DeviceId = targetDeviceId;
```

(also, I tried `targetDevice.VerizonData = newVerizonData;` instead of `newVerizonData.DeviceId = targetDeviceId;`), in debugger I see, that `targetDevice.VerizonData` has expected data and that object has expected DeviceId (`targetDeviceId`), but after `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` I don't have this verizon data at all in DB!

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing it without the mapper so create new instance and pass that to the context using context.xxx.add(instance)

Comment: @AliK added `_context.DeviceVerizons.Add(newVerizonData);`, the same behavior :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem was because Automapper maps also `Device` entity and no matter, set you DeviceId or not... This solution works:

```
        CreateMap<DeviceVerizon, DeviceVerizon>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DeviceId, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.Device, o => o.Ignore())
            ;
```